# Is there a way to use a variable in a catch block that was previously assigned in a try block?

Tags: c#, wpf, try-catch

So I've just been making a basic little calculator made up of buttons and a textbox(tbxSum).

The problem I'm having is that if an invalid sum is input I want my catch block to pick it up(which it does) and replace what's in the textbox with the most recent result in the calculator(which it doesn't).

So say I say:

3+3=6

My calculator will now put 6 in the textbox for the next sum.

So then say I did:

6//3

It's invalid which the calculator picks up, but I want the textbox value to return to 6 from the previous sum.

This is what I've tried:

```
var myButton = (Button)sender;

        if (myButton.Content.ToString() == "=")
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string s = tbxSum.Text;
            string result = "";

            if (s.Contains("("))
            {
                s = s.Replace("(", "*(");
            }

            try
            {
                var v = dt.Compute(s, "");
                tbkSum.Text = s + "=" + v.ToString();

                tbxSum.Text = v.ToString();
            }

            catch
            {   
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Sum");
                tbxSum.Text = result;
            }
        }
```

I also have a textblock(tbkSum) which shows the previous sum so I thought maybe I could take everything in there to the right of the equals sign but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: The problem is that you need to store the variable of the last good computation. So create a global variable for the class where the computation happens, at the point of a good computation, set that variable to be the same as the answer, if  a bad computation, set the text box back to the previous value (If one exists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Calculate(){
    private boolean lastGoodValueSet = false;
    private int lastGoodValue = 0;

    void buttonFunction(){
        if (myButton.Content.ToString() == "=")
        {
            //Your code
            try
            {
                var v = dt.Compute(s, "");
                tbkSum.Text = s + "=" + v.ToString();
                lastGoodValue = v;
                lastGoodValueSet = true;
            }

            catch
            {   
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Sum");
                tbxSum.Text = result;
                if (lastGoodValueSet)
                    tbxSum.Text = lastGoodValue;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is an example set of code you could use, it's a simple value that you have to store to say if a good computation has been done and if so, at the point of error we want to go back to the computation. Hope that helps! You'll want to put some kind of message to the user, so they know there was an error though.

We have to do this, as at the point of the user pressing the equals button, the value has already changed inside `tbkSum`, we need it before the user has changed the value, so the best time to grab it is at the point when we update the `tbkSum` text value at a successful calculation

This is also assuming you do not create a new instance of the `Calculate` class each time you do your computation. Otherwise you'd need to store the number somewhere else

**EDIT**
The other way to fix this issue is to instead prevent the duplicate in the first place, I read from your other comments that you control what goes into the text box by buttons on the application. Assuming all buttons go through the same method of `buttonFunction()` then you could do:

```
private char[] buttonChars = {'/','*', '+'/*e.t.c*/}
void buttonFunction(){
    string buttonPressedStr = myButton.Content.ToString();
    char buttonPressed = buttonPressedStr[0];
    int pos = Array.IndexOf(buttonChars , buttonPressed);
    if (pos > -1)
    {
        if (tbxSum.Text.Length > 0){
            char last = tbxSum.Text[tbxSum.Text.Length - 1];
            pos = Array.IndexOf(buttonChars , last);
        }
        else
            pos = 0;
        if (pos > -1){
            tbkSum.Text += buttonPressedStr;
        }
}
```

There are cleaner ways to do this, but it's an example of how you could have prevented your issue in the first place. Some explanation:

1. `buttonChars` is an array of your different button types that would be appended to your text in the box, an example is +, -, and so on
2. First it checks if the button pressed was in your collection of specified `buttonChars`
3. If so, we have to check what the last thing added to the `tbxSum` was
4. If the last thing added to `tbxSum` was again found in the `buttonChars` array, we don't want to append a string
5. Otherwise, if the `tbxSum` was empty or had another character at the end, we can append our character

Comment: You obviously better understood what this calculator does +1 :)

Comment: @BoogaWooga I've added some more code, it's not fantastic, but might help preventing the issue of having duplicate operators in the first place. There are a lot better coding practices that could be done here, however that would take writing the application in a different way. This is an interesting basis to learn from and good luck!

Comment: I've probably tried to implement this incorrectly but when I click one of the specified operators for a second time and every time after that it appends 2 of them at once

Comment: Couldn't tell you much without seeing the code I'm afraid. If the original works, feel free to stick to it, though if you want to try the other method you can ask a new question, plenty of people on SO who are willing to help and I might also be in on the question :)

Comment: I'll play around with it a bit more see if I can get it to work I think, If there's a better way I might as well try and learn it :) Won't learn much if I get people to do it for me all the time haha, but thanks for the suggestion mate, it's appreciated :)

Comment: @Draken Came up with a way to stop it after all, wouldn't mind some feedback if you find some time

Answer (score 2):

You can store the old value in a variable declard *outside* the try block and use this variable in your catch block again:

```
string oldSumValue = tbxSum.Text;

try
{
    // your code          
}
catch
{
    tbxSum.Text = oldSumValue ;
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Sum");       
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should've included a little bit more code, I've amended it now, this is all executed when the equals button is clicked, I've tried moving it up a level but that didn't work either

Comment: @BoogaWooga The solution is the same, simply store the value in a variable outside of the try block. Updated my answer.

Comment: That's what I mean though, if I punch in an invalid sum to the textbox that's the new textbox value, when the equals button is clicked this variable is what's currently in the textbox so the invalid sum gets saved to the variable. Do you think I could use an invisible textblock or something to do it if that's even possible just for the result, and if so is that bad practice?

Comment: @BoogaWooga Sorry, I think I'm confused about _what_ is in _which_ textbox. Maybe you should give your textboxes better names :) As far as I can see from your code, you change `tbxSum.Text` only at success. Since this is a calculator, you may want to set `tbxSum.ReadOnly = true` to avoid invalid user input in that textbox.

Comment: Lol should probably work on my naming, the way I'm doing it is there's a textblock (tbkSum) above the textbox(tbxSum). The user clicks a button and it puts the content in the textbox. It is read only but I set it up so when the user clicks a button it appends a value to whats currently in the textbox so it has the sum in the textbox(3+3) when the user clicks equals and when it's successful this value is taken from the textbox and put to the textblock to show the last sum that was input. So now the value in the Textblock is 3+3=6 and the textbox is now 6. The user could still punch in // or **

Comment: You could add a check to the button that sees what the last value added was to the `TextBox` and prevents those kinds of duplicates, thus removing this issue in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively I've come up with this to prevent there being:

A)Duplicate of '*' or '/'

B)Sum starting with '*' or '/'

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (tbxSum.Text == "")
        {
            btnDiv.IsEnabled = false;
            btnMult.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    protected void btnSumClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        btnDiv.IsEnabled = true;
        btnMult.IsEnabled = true;

        var myButton = (Button)sender;
        int pos = tbxSum.Text.Length;

        if (pos > 0)
        {

            if ((tbxSum.Text[pos - 1] == '/' || tbxSum.Text[pos - 1] == '*') &&
                (myButton.Content.ToString() == "/" || myButton.Content.ToString() == "*"))
            {
                int location = tbxSum.Text.Length - 1;
                tbxSum.Text = tbxSum.Text.Remove(location, 1);
            }

        }
    }
```